# Django Foreign key query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following modle

```
class PatientContact(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    contact = models.ForeignKey(PatientContact)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I can get the list of patients registered under a user:
    Patient.objects.filter(contact=uid)

How could I get the list of appointment for a user from the above model? 
Used case:
The list of appointments scheduled by user (uid=1234)
Not sure how to perform a backward relationship to get list of appointments for a given uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this isn't backward, it's just two levels deep:

```
Appointment.objects.filter(patient__contact__uid=1234)
```